# Comment flag popup is hidden when flag from the negative voted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flags, comment-flags

There is a strange display issue with the comment flag popup.

When I open a comment from the Data Explorer, the comment appeared in the top of the page. Then I click the <kbd>flag</kbd> link, the popup box is appeared but overlapped with the **Answer** box.

This strange issue occurs when the comment's answer have the negative points and the answers are ordered by **votes**.

[image: Order by Votes]

But I can manually click the partial visible part of the popup to flag the comment. Initially I found the issue in Stack Overflow and posted in its [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332278/2451726). Later I see the same issue in other SE communities too, so I posted here.

The following sample comments with negative votes, can be produce the issue:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/how-to-undo-git-add-before-commit#comment38584016_9373141)
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235017/is-women-men-girls-love-meet-die-a-valid-sentence/235038#comment506378_235038)
- [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55638/youre-out-a-dollar-what-does-that-actually-mean/55722#comment106800_55722)
- [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102160/in-sql-server-is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-selected-group-of-rows-are-locked-or/112120#comment203480_112120)
- [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9036/the-lion-and-the-zebras#comment28642_9052)
- [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/827/what-caused-and-ended-the-time-loop-in-groundhog-day/831#comment73979_831)

The same is in the below GIF format:

[image: GIF for the issue]

It happened in the Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer browsers.

Comment: I have seen the flag dialog lose opacity when the answer gets gray, but I have never repro'ed this.

Comment: @hichris123 shouldn't the dupe target be this? it has an answer.

Comment: It can always be reposted, @Yvette. :) Since that one was a year earlier, and both are about the same quality, I figured the older one could be the target.

Comment: @hichris123 I didn't see it was a dupe (obviously). I thought that is they have similar upvotes, that the one with the answer should be the target. Anyway I believe it's status by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in [user3956566's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284084/comment-flag-popup-is-hidden-when-flag-from-the-negative-voted-answers/284110#284110), the root cause here is partial opacity applied to the children of elements with the `comments` class.

Given the only children that actually *need* opacity are the children of the elements with the `comment-text` class, the simple solution is to just apply the styling to those instead.

With this done, the transparency and answer-form collisions no longer occur.

Answer (score 4):

What is happening is the comment flag dialog box is in the same div as the downvoted answer, which is set to fade without focus, so when the cursor brushes the following div, which is often a post answer box, the dialog box is fading with the downvoted answer.

**With a post new answer box beneath the down vote answer, as you have demonstrated:**

[image]

---

**The same can be demonstrated with a Question status beneath the low voted answer:**

[image]

---

**The pop up is in the same div as the answer:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**The question status notification is in a new div:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe this is status by design.

Comment: Relevant CSS is `.downvoted-answer .comments,.downvoted-answer .post-signature,.downvoted-answer .post-text,.downvoted-answer .vote>*{opacity:.5;transition:opacity .5s}`. The comments flag dialog is a child of the div with the `comments` class.